# CAML Query to retrieve First Name using Email Id of users in Sharepoint

Tags: workflow, caml-query, user-accounts

I am creating a custom workflow which gets activated whenever some data is entered in a particular list. One of the field in this list is a column for Email ID of the a user( not necessarily the logged in user).

Based on this,**I have to write a CAML query which selects the First Name based on the user's Email ID in SharePoint 2007**.
Is there a way to get rest of the user details from email id?

Comment: What is the type of Email ID column? Is it just a plain Text or a User column?

Answer (score 1):

You can query SiteUserInfoList to retrieve user by email. With result of query you can find SPUser by id.

```
var web = SPContext.Current.Web;

SPQuery query       = new SPQuery();
query.Query         = "<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"EMail\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">sample@microsoft.com</Value></Eq>";
var items           = web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItems(query);
var user            = web.SiteUsers.GetByID(items[0].ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to read from the same list with data from other columns. Please correct me if I am wrong.

In that case, try using the [U2U Caml Query builder](http://www.u2u.net/Tools/wincamlquerybuilder/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) to test your CAML queries.

Install the CAML builder, point it to your site, read the particular list. You can give filters and order the results accordingly.

Comment: Sorry if the details are not clear. The problem is that email id is entered by people picker( from AD). When creating a new item for a list, theres a column for email id ( which gets picked from AD). Based on this emial id i need to retrieve the rest of the details for the user using CAML query. Is it possible?